# SSRS in SharePoint mode Performance Degradation - Explanation and suggestions

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We discovered a significant **Reporting Services performance degradation** when using **Go To Report** actions in SharePoint mode.

Basically, after a few Go to report actions, the price paid to keep all previous executions alive is getting higher than the time it takes to render the current report.

Each time a user click on a Go to report action, a new execution id is generated, added to the View State and a row is inserted in SessionData (TempDB database). This row is set to expire after a configured amount of time (default = 10 minutes). When the session has expired, the row will be purged.

There are two mechanism to prevent all previous executions to expire:

•    Every time the user use a Go to report action, all previous report executions get “touched” in order to prevent them to expire. It means that multiple rows in SessionData table will have their Expiration column updated. This add significant amount of time to the report rendering (it is not done on a background thread …)

•    There is a keep alive HTTP request that is done automatically if the user leave his browser open on a SSRS report without interacting with it. This too will “touch” all previous report executions to prevent their expiration.

All this was done to enable the user to use the SSRS toolbar back button. When using back, there is an event on the server with the execution id. The server is able to retrieve all information about the previous execution (ex. report, parameter values) from the SessionData table and render the report in an efficient way.

In our experience, users will never go back more than 2-3 times using back. There is currently no way to limit the history length (the number of times a user can use back) to better balance the user flexibility and the performance.

So the history keeps growing forever (particularly if Go to report is used as navigation between reports). As it grows, performance is degrading so much that users are better off closing the browser window and starting again.

---

**Did you ever notice this behaviour?** It doesn't happen with Go To Url actions.

Microsoft is now aware of this issue, but may only consider a way around it for the next release (2016) which is not very practical. You can help by voting on these three connect.microsoft.com entries because they use that a lot to give priorities:

- [Configurable value for the number of report executions to keep in the
  history (for back purpose)](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/884197/configurable-value-for-the-number-of-report-executions-to-keep-in-the-history-for-back-purpose)
- [Use HTTP POST for Go To Url actions](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/884183/use-http-post-for-go-to-url-actions)
- [Easy to reproduce, significant SSRS performance degradation when using Go To Report actions](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/833306/easy-to-reproduce-significant-ssrs-performance-degradation-when-using-go-to-report-actions)

Comment: Thanks for the "heads up" - I've just voted.

Comment: Thanks, more votes == more chances of having our favorite reporting platform improved. :-)